# jquery replace parent select with an input, if selected option value is this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace entire dropdown - select element, with an input field, if a selected option value is, say, 777.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mylist").change(function(){     
        //var val = $(":selected",this).val();
        if(this.val == "777"){
            $("#mylist").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="xxx" required="required" />');
        }
    }) // change-function ends
}) // doc-ready ends
```

```html
<select id="mylist">
    <option value="777">Nothing exists</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

But it's not working. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try replacing this.val with $(this).val() ?

Comment: What part is not working? And should you have functionality to return the newly-created `<input>` with a `<select>` at all?

Comment: @DavidThomas INPUT is not coming, on selecting 777 value from dropdown. How i return newly-created <input> .?

Comment: My comment is the solution ;) but you look at solutions written down there too @luna.romania

Answer (score 4):

`.val` is not a valid property in javascript, it is jquery method.

You should either use clean javascript  `this.value` or jquery `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val` here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mylist").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "777"){
      $("#mylist").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="xxx" required="required" />');
    }
  }) ;// change-function ends
}); // doc-ready ends
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mylist">
      <option value="777">Nothing exists</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: `this.val` cannot work, but `this.value` works and it's faster than `$(this).val()` :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#mylist").change(function(){

      var val = $("option:selected",this).val();
      if(val == "777"){

      $("#mylist").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="xxx" required="required" />');
      }
      });
      });



      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `val` which is not a `property` or `function` you need to use `.value` Try this

```
if(this.value == "777"){
   $("#mylist").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="xxx" required="required" />');
 }
```

Comment: Faster than $(this).val() which also works, so +1 :)

Comment: @Julqas yes it is native property so faster.